# R Create function to add water year column

Tags: r, date, datetime, time-series

I want to be able to create a water year column for a time series.  The US water year is from Oct-Sept and is considered the year it ends on.  For example the 2014 water year is from October 1, 2013 - September 30, 2014.

This is the US water year, but not the only water year.  Therefore I want to enter in a start month and have a water year calculated for the date.

For example if my data looks like

```
        date
2008-01-01 00:00:00
2008-02-01 00:00:00
2008-03-01 00:00:00
2008-04-01 00:00:00
       .
       .
       .
2008-12-01 00:00:00
```

I want my function to work something like:

```
wtr_yr <- function(data, start_month) {

does stuff

}
```

Then my output would be

```
wtr_yr(data, 2)

         date                    wtr_yr
    2008-01-01 00:00:00           2008
    2008-02-01 00:00:00           2009 
    2008-03-01 00:00:00           2009
    2008-04-01 00:00:00           2009
           .
           .
           .
    2009-01-01 00:00:00           2009 
    2009-02-01 00:00:00           2010
    2009-03-01 00:00:00           2010
    2009-04-01 00:00:00           2010
```

I started by breaking the date up into separate columns, but I don't think that is the best way to go about it.  Any advice?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can use POSIXlt to come up with an answer.

```
wtr_yr <- function(dates, start_month=9) {
  # Convert dates into POSIXlt
  dates.posix = as.POSIXlt(dates)
  # Year offset
  offset = ifelse(dates.posix$mon >= start_month - 1, 1, 0)
  # Water year
  adj.year = dates.posix$year + 1900 + offset
  # Return the water year
  adj.year
}
```

Let's now use this function in an example.

```
# Sample input vector
dates = c("2008-01-01 00:00:00",
"2008-02-01 00:00:00",
"2008-03-01 00:00:00",
"2008-04-01 00:00:00",
"2009-01-01 00:00:00",
"2009-02-01 00:00:00",
"2009-03-01 00:00:00",
"2009-04-01 00:00:00")

# Display the function output
wtr_yr(dates, 2)

# Combine the input and output vectors in a dataframe
df = data.frame(dates, wtr_yr=wtr_yr(dates, 2))
```

Comment: I'm glad you like it!

Comment: You can also use the waterYear function available in the USGS R packge `smwrBase` (available from https://github.com/USGS-R/smwrBase). There are also other useful hydrological analysis tools in this package.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem a while back but dealing with fiscal years that started in October.  I found [this function](https://gist.github.com/jbryer/5412193) which also computes the quarters within the year.  For one part, I only wanted it to output the fiscal year, so I edited a tiny part of the function to do that.  There is surely a much cleaner/efficient way of doing it, but this should work for smaller data sets.  Here is the edited function:

```
getYearQuarter <- function(x,
        firstMonth=7,
        fy.prefix='FY',
        quarter.prefix='Q',
        sep='-',
        level.range=c(min(x), max(x)) ) {
if(level.range[1] > min(x) | level.range[2] < max(x)) {
        warning(paste0('The range of x is greater than level.range. Values ',
            'outside level.range will be returned as NA.'))
}
quarterString <- function(d) {
        year <- as.integer(format(d, format='%Y'))
        month <- as.integer(format(d, format='%m'))
        y <- ifelse(firstMonth > 1 & month >= firstMonth, year+1, year)
        q <- cut( (month - firstMonth) %% 12, breaks=c(-Inf,2,5,8,Inf),
            labels=paste0(quarter.prefix, 1:4))
        return(paste0(fy.prefix, substring(y,3,4)))
}
vals <- quarterString(x)
levels <- unique(quarterString(seq(
        as.Date(format(level.range[1], '%Y-%m-01')),
        as.Date(format(level.range[2], '%Y-%m-28')), by='month')))
return(factor(vals, levels=levels, ordered=TRUE))
}
```

Your input vector should be type *Date*, and then specify the start month.  Assuming you have a data frame(df) with the 'date' column as in your question, this should do the trick.

```
df$wtr_yr <- getYearQuarter(df$date, firstMonth=10)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also achieve adding a column by water year by using the "lfstat" package

https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/lfstat/versions/0.9.4/topics/water_year

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30989988)